# What is the recommended YouTube 3D stereo parallax?

Tags: youtube, stereo-3d

I am to render 3D stereo videos and don't have enough specifications.

E.g. I have captured Duke Nukem 3D in Crystal Eyes VR mode and post processing it in MathCAD. Source resolution is 320x200, and parallax is 56 pixels. Parallax is more commonly measured in percents, so I divide 56 by 320 and get 17.5%. This is excellent for my display in full screen mode, but not for big 3D TV, so I should probably make it less, but how much? I can see no numbers on YouTube help portal.